# Vagrant NFS shares in Fedora 21 blocked by firewalld

Tags: nfs, fedora, vagrant, firewalld

My NFS shares created by vagrant are being blocked by firewalld. The host is Fedora 21 and the client Debian 7.7. This is common problem that should be solved by opening the firewall for NFS as seen [here](http://blog.bak1an.so/blog/2014/03/23/fedora-vagrant-nfs/) but this isn't working in my case.

This is the output of `firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=internal`:

`internal (active)
  interfaces: vboxnet0 vboxnet1
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns mountd nfs rpc-bind samba-client ssh
  ports: 2049/udp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:`

I'm not really sure where to go from here - firewalld doesn't support logging of dropped packets so I can't see where it is going wrong. If I disable the firewall it works perfectly. Add a comment if you need any additional information and I will update the question.

**UPDATE**

I have also tried the same rules in the default zone, moving the vboxnet interfaces over. No change.

Comment: you need to open 2049/tcp as well

Comment: The "nfs" listed in services opens that port, however I have just tried this but it hasn't fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to notice that vboxnet0 was not connecting when the firewall was enabled. After messing around for some time I tried reinstalling VirtualBox from RPMForge rather than the copy direct from Oracle. The vboxnet0 interface then started connecting and the firewall issues disappeared. It looks like there is an issue with the Oracle version of this package and firewalld. Hope this helps someone else.